# DB2 instance creation failed while running db2icrt

Tags: linux, db2, centos7

I have installed DB2 10.5 server in my centos 7 VM.
I am trying to create a DB2 instance via running db2icrt

```
./db2icrt -u db2fenc1 db2inst1
```

But the command fails by issuing this :

```
Operating system information: Linux 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64.#1 SMP Fri Mar 6 11:36:42 UTC 2015 x86_64
ERROR: The host name "vm65x148.acg.ips" is invalid. Specify a valid host name.
ERROR: The "db2icrt" command failed. Ensure the command parameters are valid,
that errors reported in the log file are fixed, then rerun the command.
```

The entry in my /etc/hosts file is this

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that vm65x148.acg.ips is the hostname of your machine. Make sure that this hostname can be resolved on the OS level, then try creating the instance again.

for more detail, see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21615752

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the post by Peter Schuetze ,my /etc/hosts file was missing the entry of my VM id . So I tried to fix the issue by editing my /etc/hosts files
This is the initial entry in my /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

This is how it looked after editing

```
127.0.0.1   vm65x148.acg.ips localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

After that I restarted the daemon like this :

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/network restart
```

Then I tried to create the DB2 instanceand this time it worked
Hope this helps someone else

Comment: I would be careful with adding it to the loopback adapter. I would have used the public IP that you used to connect to the VM.